# Delete chat rooms ejabberd

Tags: iphone, xmpp, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd 2.1 for my chat application.We have used multi user chat rooms.I want to clear out all my existing chat rooms from ejabberd.Is it possible from the admin part.Any ejebberdctl command available for this?

Help is highly appreciable

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
ejabberdctl muc-purge 0
```

May fullfill your need.
The man entry for this command is the following:

```
ejabberdctl  muc-purge days
```

> Destroy MUC rooms with zero activity (no messages in history) in the
>       last **days** days.

Answer (score 1):

I used that for list and delete all muc rooms in the server

```
sudo ejabberdctl muc_online_rooms global | sed -e 's/@/ /g' | xargs -n 2 -I {} bash -c 'sudo ejabberdctl destroy_room {}'
```

In my case i need use sudo, if you dont need just remove it.